# Creating a list of lists in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the `a1, a2, and a3` lists that I import from my excel file.

```
W = 4
T = 5
I = 206

a1 = []
for w in range(7, W+7):
    a1.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
a2 = []
for w in range(13, W+13):
    a2.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
a3 = []
for w in range(19, W+19):
    a3.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
```

As you see, they are different columns of the same sheet. I want to combine these lists (columns) in another list, say list `a`. I am using:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3]
```

However, I want them to be generic; if I have `a4, a5` and so on, I want them to be added to the list `a` automatically. I could create the following logic that I could use:

```
a = []
for i in range(7, 7+6*T, T+1):
    for w in range(i, W+i):
        .........................
```

I am missing the above part to append everything to a list without creating individual `a1, a2, a3`.... lists. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `a = [[ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I] for w in range(i, W+i)] for i in range(7,19,6)]`

Comment: You commented the first actually, I wish you had written this as an answer. I realized I was just missing brackets. Once I add `(7, 7+6*T, T+1)` for the last range, it works. Thanks @Fabricator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating individual named lists you can create a temporary list each time and append it.

```
a = []
for i in range(7, 7+6*T, T+1):
    tmp = [] # temporary list
    for w in range(i, W+i):
         tmp.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
    a.append(tmp)
```

Comment: This will end up with `a = [[a1].[a2],[a3]]` and not `a = [a1, a2, a3]`. You don't need to create tmp because `ProjectData.col_values` already returns a list.

Comment: Nope, it works perfectly fine. That is how I want it. Thanks @Neo.

Comment: @bikemule `tmp` is equivalent to `a1`, `a2` and `a3`. Their list is `a`, same as in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop logic is set up properly; just create a list like `a_sub` every time the outer loop is run once more, and then append values to the sublist in the inner loop, then append the sublist to `a` at the end of the outer loop. Try this:

```
a = []
for i in range(7, 7+6*T, T+1):
    a_sub = []
    for w in range(i, W+i):
        a_sub.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
    a.append(a_sub)
```

Alternatively:

```
a = []
for i in range(7, 7+6*T, T+1):
    a.append([]) # Append an empty list
    for w in range(i, W+i):
        a[-1].append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I]) # a[-1] is the last element of a, which is the sublist you just created
```

Alternatively:

```
a=[[ProjectData.col_values(w+i,3)[:I]for w in range(W)]for i in range(7,7+6*T,T+1)] # Don't use this because it's unreadable
```

If you like the last one, use this instead for readability

```
a = [[ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I] for w in range(i, W + i)] for i in range(7, 7 + 6 * T, T + 1]
```

Slightly longer but this isn't code golf ya know :P I'd recommend using the second one personally.

Although being a code-golfer, you'll see things like the third one show up in my code sometimes... :P

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. I was just stuck. It was very simple and of course, the third one looks the most beautiful.

Comment: @user8028576 You're certainly welcome! And do you really think the third one looks the most beautiful? I think the fourth one looks best because it's essentially the same as the third one but you can actually *read* it which is sometimes helpful during coding... :P

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
for i in range(7, 7+6*T, T+1):
    for w in range(i, W+i):
        a.append(ProjectData.col_values(w, 3)[:I])
```

`append` adds an item to list `a`. The item in this case is a list. If you do it three times, it adds the three lists. Then a[1] = the list a1.

You don't need to assign the list to a temp var to add it to `a`.

Comment: Put an `enter` after the second colon. It will improve readability.